# Getting Foreign Key voilation error in AWS Database migration service

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, postgresql-9.6, aws-dms

I am migrating my unencrypted postgres database to encypted database using AWS database management service but getting this error.

```
[TARGET_LOAD ]E: RetCode: SQL_ERROR SqlState: 0A000 NativeError: 1 Message: ERROR: cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint; Error while executing the query [1022502] (ar_odbc_stmt.c:4622)
```

To resolve this error i have even set session_replication_role to 'replica'. but i am getting same result.

Any suggestions how can i resolve this error?